# Google Brand Account can't open sidebar app launcher

Tags: google-account, google-brand-account

I made a Google Brand Account (for the purposes of moving an existing YouTube channel to that account). Whenever I log in to that account, the right-side navigation sidebar (which should pop up from one of the top-right buttons) fails to load and gives the error:

> Can't seem to load the app launcher right now. Try again or go to the
> Google Products page.

Or alternatively:

> Something went wrong. Refresh to try again or choose another account.

It's been in this state consistently since making the account over a week ago. I'm a bit anxious about adding content to this account, thinking it may be in some unstable state and subject to total loss. Is there any fix or resolution for this?

[image: Google Brand Account app launcher sidebar fail]

Note that the [Google Products](https://about.google/products/?tab=kh) page linked in the error message fails to have any relevant information on the immediate issue.